# Core Data - batch handling the attributes of fetched results

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've got a bunch of managed objects that i'm fetching from a managed object context. These object have a imageFilePath attribute, which is just a path to an image data object ive saved to a directory on the phone. My question is this - what is the best way to batch convert all these data objects into an array of photos?

I'm considering just iterating thru the array of the managed objects, but that seems somewhat inefficient. I could also perhaps create a separate entity from this attribute in my model, and grab them directly.

Is there a way i could apply a block to each result of my fetch as it comes in?

thanks!

Comment: What is the code in your iteration? And by "array of photos" you mean an array of UIImage? And lastly are you presenting all those photos at once or only few now and the rest later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about the Core Data side of things, take a look at the `fetchBatchSize` you can set on `NSFetchRequest`. You'll have to experiment a bit to see what size will work best for you, but something like `25` is a good starting point. That way Core Data will not fetch all objects from disk at once, but fault them in 25 at a time. You still see a normal `NSArray` and Core Data does all the magic in the background.

Comment: ..and if you combine Daniel's suggestion with calling `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` on the resulting NSArray it basically boils down to what you wanted: "apply a block to each result of my fetch as it comes in". You should be able to find the balance you want for memory usage by tweaking the `fetchBatchSize`.